# Cannot umount USB drive because it's "not mounted" despite being able to list its content

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4

I've connected external USB drive to my raspberry pi.

```
sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL

UUID                                 NAME        FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL  MODEL
                                     sda                931.5G                   SAMSUNG_HD103SJ
2d895223-03fe-422c-8266-2542b8f19787 └─sda1      ext4   931.5G
                                     mmcblk0             14.4G
9F2D-0578                            ├─mmcblk0p1 vfat     256M /boot      boot
efc2ea8b-042f-47f5-953e-577d8860de55 └─mmcblk0p2 ext4    14.2G /          rootfs
```

Than I've mounted it as follow:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/samsung
```

The `ls /mnt/samsung` gives me the `sample.jpg` file inside listed.

Right after I've tried to do `sudo umount /mnt/samsung` but I got error:

```
umount: /mnt/samsung: not mounted.
```

**How is that possible?**

I've also changed ownership of `mnt/samsung` with `chown www-data:www-data` because I need access to this disk from my PHP script.

I can see files there, but they appear to be... local? When I remove the disk, content of `mnt/samsung` is still there... all the files.

I tried to reboot after adding this line to `/etc/fstab` with no result:

```
UUID=2d895223-03fe-422c-8266-2542b8f19787 /mnt/samsung ext4 defaults,auto,nofail,umask=000,allow_$
```

the `mount` command returns:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1873872k,nr_inodes=117736,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=401192k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Comment: What is the output of `mount`? It might have had a hiccup, e.g. short power outage, and be unmounted. Especially when talking about a Pi and its limited power capabilities.

Comment: @FelixJN I've added the output of `mount`. I feel like `mnt/samsung` is just an folder on local system and not really anything on the USB disk. I can see files there, but they appear to be... local? I've also changed ownership of `mnt/samsung` with `chown www-data:www-data` because I need access to this disk from my PHP script.

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to be mounted at all. `/mnt` is nothing but a directory as others, it is just the standard (one of the standards) where you mount. One might mount on any directory. I.e. you just created a local directory and local files. I assume you wrote to that location while the USB was actually unmounted.

Comment: @FelixJN ok, I see. So, how to mount this USB? It has external power supply (it's Samsung Story 1T station) so I don't think ti's Pi power capability that is causing this.

Comment: Well, just use `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. It does not matter if there is content in the mountpoint (i.e. the old `samsung` direcotry). This data will not be deleted, it is just hidden and will show up again after you unmount.